# how to use two layouts in Recyclearview Android

Tags: android

i have already search web to find a solution.

i have two layouts in my activity and in first layout i have my `recyclearview` and in second i have a textview that i want to `settext` by clicking one of items in recyclear.

so in `onBindViewHolder` i added the click listener.
but i have no access to the second layout to settext.

i used `layoutinflator` and created view from that.
and i could get values like `gettext()` but `settext()` is not working with no error!!

how can i fix that?

UPDATE:

```
 View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.etelaie_activity, null);
    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.etelaie_activity_title);
    Toast.makeText(context, tt.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    this.title = title;
    this.context = context;

        tt.setText("ff");
```

`gettext()` is working but settext wont apply.

Comment: Please, provide you code.

Comment: i added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send callback from your `Adapter` to `Activity`. `View` of `RecyclerView`'s item is different from `View` of `Activity`.

```
TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.etelaie_activity_title);
```

You inflated `View` and accessing its default written text(might be a text which you put inside XML file) but where this `View` is shown on UI? You  didn't set this `View` on UI.

Comment: Where you are using this View? Please check updated answer

Comment: view is in my activity. [link](http://s9.picofile.com/file/8299529718/photo_2017_07_03_22_30_32.jpg) see the pic. that long text at bottom is the text i want to change. and the only place i have defined that is in my `onbind` mehod in `adapter`

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface like:

```
public interface MyAdapterCallback {
    void updateText(String text);
}
```

Implement this in your Activity:

```
public class YourActivity implements MyAdapterCallback {
. . .

@Override
void updateText(String text){
    textView.setText(text);
}
. . .
}
```

Create adapter with:

```
Constructor(its parameter.. , MyAdapterCallback callback)
```

Inside `onClick` in `adapter`: call

```
callback.updateText(list.get(position))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thats exactly @Rasi  did for me. tnx.